# Where does Eclipse store the information regarding "Run Favorites" or "Debug Favorites"?

Tags: eclipse, configuration, favorites

Where does Eclipse store the information regarding "Run Favorites" or "Debug Favorites"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are stored in the file `launchConfigurationHistory.xml` in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.ui` directory.

The file contains various launch related settings, favorites are in the `<favorites>` sections.

Note: It is probably not safe to modify this file while Eclipse is running.

Update:

The launch configuration file itself `name.launch` in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches` directory is also updated to say which favorites group it is in.

Update:

If a xxx.launch file is in a favorites group it contains something like:

```xml
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.run"/>
</listAttribute>
```

(along with lots of other launch related entries)

Update:

You can look at the launch configurations in a plugin using:

```java
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager(); 

ILaunchConfiguration [] configs = manager.getLaunchConfigurations();
```

The `IDebugUIConstants.ATTR_FAVORITE_GROUPS` attribute of the `ILaunchConfiguration` should contain any favorites groups the launch is in.

Comment: Hi, grrg, for the first directory you mentioned in your post, I can find the settings related to favorites. However, for .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches, I couldn't find the any settings related to "favorites"

Comment: Added the contents of the xxx.launch file if it is in a favorites list to the answer

Comment: Hi, greg, thank you for your previous answers. I have done some test about the launchConfigurationHistory.xml file. And I realise that the changes that I made about the "Run Favorites" wouldn't be saved to the file until I close the workspace or the Eclipse. Is there anyway to get the runtime data about the "Run Favorites"?

Comment: Added how to access launch configuration from a plugin

Comment: Hi Greg, I have tried your method in my plugin. "ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();" However, the line of code didn't work. When I debug the application, the executor goes directly to the method sendEvent (Event event) in the EventTable.class (I put the code in a button even handler).